# GridGain support answerers

Tags: discussion, self-promotion, product-support

This question, https://stackoverflow.com/q/32726426/1927206, arrived yesterday. As far as I'm concerned, it is unanswerable in its present state, and I can't imagine other than wildly broad answers without knowing a good deal about the client's system(s). It has so far attracted two close votes.

Today, it has received two answers. One answer is definitely by a GridGain developer (working on the software itself). The other looks like a general bit of blurb, the type of answer such a broad question attracts.

Looking into it, https://stackoverflow.com/users/3769473/kuaw26?tab=profile is an GridGain developer (picture matches on support forum), he may be https://stackoverflow.com/users/3435642/alexey, or that may be just another developer at the same site with the same first-name, and the other top GridGain answerers, https://stackoverflow.com/users/1689455/dmitriy and https://stackoverflow.com/users/3604242/valentin look to be developers there also.

I thought to approach them each by pining, and explain that they should be up-front about who they are, with at the very least a Disclaimer in their answers. A mention in their Profile would be good, but up to them (probably).

Then I thought "should all the existing answers have a Disclaimer?", and I thought, "Yes", and there are over 150 of them.

I also thought, from the bad question which brought me to the tag originally, that there is a thin line between useful documentation suggestions and the start of a sales pitch.

So:

1. Should all the answers have a Disclaimer and, if Yes, how is that best achieved?
2. Is there advice from SO (as in the new company) on the thin line which crosses to promotion, and if Yes, how to communicate that to them?
3. Although any individual can ping one or all four of them about including a Disclaimer on new answers, is there a better way to arrange that (perhaps as part of 2 above)?

I started to sort this out myself, then thought to use the Contact Us, then wondered about the existing answers, so came here.

I'm sure that good GridGain questions are welcome here, and anyone asking those questions will be happy with the quality of results from these four guys, I just think they need to do things a little more formally.

I don't think they are offloading Product Support here, as they have their own active community on their site, they are just hitting here to cover questions raised here.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion

Comment: @jonrsharpe thanks, that seems to cover 2 and 3, although it could benefit from some emphasis on the "don't answer poor questions", perhaps. I could easily ping that link to the guys.

Comment: However, doesn't cover the issue of the existing 150+ answers with no Disclaimer.

Comment: (Ignoring the poor question at the beginning) Since when does providing product support for a question _about your product_ qualify as self-promotion?

Comment: @KevinBrown When it doesn't include a Disclaimer?

Comment: @BillWoodger Yes. There's a difference between "hey, you're having an issue with xyz but you should use foobar instead" and "you're having an issue with foobar, here's how to fix it". The first one should definitely have a disclaimers (it's where self-promotion becomes spam), but the second one is lacking the self-promotion aspect.

Comment: @KevinBrown Sure, that's why you ignored the poor question. So that bit is easily agreed. Are you suggesting that there is a "if you're not overtly (even if trying to avoid being overt by being sneaky) promoting, you don't need a Disclaimer"? I'd disagree (drive-by viewer thinks "hey, cool, smart guys elsewhere use this product, let's look into it" vs (with Disclaimer) "hey, they've got good support".

Comment: @BillWoodger Bill, any chance you can have a disclaimer yourself? I looked at your profile and it seems anonymous.

Comment: @Dmitriy what goes in your Profile is up to you. A user can even plain advertise something there. The disclaimer would be in your answers, all of them (at least new ones). I'm not suggesting there is anything suspicious or wrong going on (except that particular question should not have been answered, because it is impossible to answer) with you and your colleagues posts, which I see as detailed, helpful and very professional otherwise. Just no disclaimer was why I came here.

Comment: @BillWoodger Disagree. I care about your identity, when reading your comments here, for the same reasons you care about mine. If you don't want to update your stack overflow profile, perhaps you could provide a link to your linkedin profile here, as a disclaimer?

Comment: @Dmitriy I'm not sure what you are disagreeing with? You mean you agree with Kevin Brown's comment and that you think you don't need a disclaimer in your answers? Perhaps that's open to interpretation, but see here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior and here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion. Don't read anything specific into any of the headings in the links from my point of view, it is just that those two reference your situation, at least in part. Although there does seem to be conflicting advice there as well. Then we sort things out here.

Comment: @BillWoodger Apache Ignite is an open source Apache project, which has nothing to do with GridGain. Apache Ignite community monitors stack overflow for questions about Apache Ignite and provides answers. As a matter of fact, Apache Ignite website suggests just that: https://ignite.apache.org/community/resources.html.  Every other Apache project does the same. I have never seen anyone add disclaimers on SO, and believe that they are not needed, especially for an open source Apache project.

Comment: @Dmitriy OK, can you add that as an answer? Are you also saying since you (and no-one else) does a disclaimer for Ignite, there's no need for you to do one for GridGain? I'll update my question to remove the reference to Ignite (included because of the "Ad" on the GridGain website, which I didn't realise was an Ad).

Comment: Bill, could you give me an example of propper disclaimer? Just to better understand what we are discussing here.

Comment: @kuaw26 here, for instance: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32010620/1927206

Comment: @kuaw26 another example: here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28778202/1927206. As far as I know, they don't have to be anything complicated or formal. They are not supposed to contain links, email addresses or telephone numbers for product support, however.Questions asked here, if they are on-topic, are best answered here, which you are all already doing, I think.

Comment: @BillWoodger, thanks, now I see. It really make sense to add such disclaimer.